# Spring EL template in a spring bean definition

Tags: spring, spring-el

I have a bean that has a map injected. The entries in the map are of type myBean (see below) and are defined in my spring XML. It may be that not all properties of myBean are defined in the xml, so I thought I would provide defaults in the form of a template where the variable bit in the template is provided by another property that will be present (p1 below). I hope that makes sense.

I am sure there are other ways to achieve this; well, I know there are, but I am new to Spring and I came across Spring EL and it sounded like it was suited to this kind of thing, so I tried this:

```
            <bean id="myDefaults" class="com.myco.MyDefaults">
              <property name="prop1" value="abc#{this.p1}def"/>
            </bean>

            <bean id="myBean" class="com.myco.MyBean" abstract="true">
                            <property name="theDefaults" ref="myDefaults"/>
            </bean>
```

In MyBean the value of p1 is 100, and I was hoping that the value of theDefaults would be abc100def, but instead I get an error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'myDefaults' defined in class path resource [myapp-spring.xml]:
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'this' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
```

Thanks for any help

Paul

Answer (score 0):

The variable is `#this`, not `this` but in any case, it's not needed in this context, it's implied.

Use `value="abc#{p1}def"`

Comment: Thank you. I think my question was ill defined - p1 is a property of com.myco.MyBean.

Comment: In that case, it's `value="abc#{myBean.p1}def`. However, since `myBean` is abstract, it won't work (you need to reference a concrete bean).